# Fixed points of $S^2\times S^2$ and $S^2\times S^2\times S^2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Consider the rotation about the $z$-axis on $S^2$. We know that $S^2$ has two fixed points which are north and South Pole.

I want to learn the fixed points of $S^2\times S^2$ and of $S^2\times S^2\times S^2$ with respect to rotation.

Comment: Did you already think about $S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1$? These spaces can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, so you can easily picture them.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spheres or topological spaces. If you have function $f:X\to X$ what are the fixed points of $f\times f:X\times X\to X\times X$?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you rotate one of the factors or all of them.

In you rotated just the first factor then you obtain two copies of $S^{2}$ or $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ respectively.

If you rotate all the factors then you obtain $4$ or $8$ isolated fixed points respectively.